# Need to format 5 disks in parallel

Tags: xargs, parallelism, mkfs

I tried this

`xargs -p 5  -n1 mke2fs -t ext4 /dev/sd[d-p]1`

and got this

`[/dev/mapper]# seq 1 15 | xargs -p 5 -n 1   mke2fs -t ext4 /dev/sd[b-p]1 
5 -n 1 mke2fs -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1 /dev/sdg1 /dev/sdh1 /dev/sdi1 /dev/sdj1 /dev/sdk1 /dev/sdl1 /dev/sdm1 /dev/sdn1 /dev/sdo1 /dev/sdp1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 ?...`

Also tried this

`[/dev/mapper]# xargs -p 5 -n 1   mke2fs -t ext4 /dev/sd[b-p]1`

and got nothing. Any ideas? what ami doing swo

Comment: That puts a heavy I/O load, and doing it in parallel doesn't make any sense unless they are connected to separate controllers

Comment: @vonbrand Are you sure? If the disks are slow SATA disks, then I would imagine most time was spent waiting for the platter to spin/seeking. Have you tested your claim? If so would you share the numbers with us?

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU Parallel you would do this:

```
parallel -P 5 mke2fs -t ext4 ::: /dev/sd[d-p]1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 echo -e "/dev/sdb\n/dev/sdc\n/dev/sdd" | xargs -P0 -n1  mkfs.ext4
```

Comment: `xargs` delimits by blank spaces by default, so you don't need the `\n` there at all.